# how to override a method with plugin

Tags: overrides, magento2.3.5-p2

Hi I'm using very nice plugin 'login-as-customer' by magefan.
I'd like to override an execute method of login-as-customer.
this is first time to try overriding third pirty's controller so I stuck now.

I put files like this and expect to ignite Plugin/Login but does not.
how can i solve this?

```
MyModule
├── Plugin
│   └── Login.php
├── etc
│   ├── di.xml
│   └── module.xml
└── registration.php
```

di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>                                                                                                                                                                             
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
   <type name="Magefan\LoginAsCustomer\Controller\Login\Index">
        <plugin name="intercept_login" type="MyCompany\MyModule\Plugin\Login" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

```
namespace MyCompany\MyModule\Plugin;

class Login
{
    /**
     * Login as customer action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */

    public function aroundExecute()
    {
        echo "here";
        die;
    }
}
```

finary, i want to inject an admin info into customer session. after i could solve this problem, i gonna write script in the aroundExceute.

Comment: Have you executed di compile &  cleared cache  ?

Comment: thanks. i forgot to write it.i did setup:upgrade, setup:di:compile, cache:clean.

Comment: You might need to pass original controller instance in to     public function aroundExecute()
argument.

Comment: It works! I really appreciate you.

Comment: Great, please mark answer as right. if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to pass original controller instance in to     public function aroundExecute()
argument.

Comment: Okay. I remove the flag.